# Graphical method in linear programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

[This page](https://accounting-simplified.com/management/limiting-factor-analysis/linear-programming/graphical-example.html) describes the graphical method to solve a linear program. The formulation is as follows.

$$\begin{alignat}{2} \max &\quad Z = 200W + 100B\\ \text{s.t.} &\quad  1W + 0.8B &&\leq 4000\\ &\quad 0.004W + 0.001B &&\leq 10\\ &\quad W, B &&\geq 0\end{alignat}$$

[image: Graph is:]

The solution given is:

> Co-ordinates of the optimum point are approximately 1850 W and 2750 B (1850, 2750).

What would be an easy way to calculate the optimal solution in addition to an estimate seen from graph (rather than the simplex method)? Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the example you shared with two variables and two constraints, as you're seeing from the graph, your solution lies at the intersection of the two constraints (not considering the non-negativity constraints). So, just solve that system of equations and you get the values for $B$ and $W$ (which should give you $B = \frac{30000}{11}$ and $W = \frac{20000}{11}$.)

If you want to go further and try the optimum values in your objective function, there are four corner points: $(0,0), (3000, 0), (0, 5000), (\frac{20000}{11}, \frac{30000}{11})$. Place these values in your objective function and you get the objective value of each point as well.

Comment: If it makes it easier, multiply the first equation by 10 and the second one by 1000 to get rid of the decimal points in the coefficients of $B$ and $W$. Then solve that system of linear equations. i.e. $10W+8B=40,000; 4W+B=10,000$. You'll get the above results (or if you prefer the decimal values, $B=30000/11=2727.3$ and $W=20000/11=1818.2$)

Comment: thank you for the perfect answer and explanation!

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad it helped.